# PerformPostRestoreFixup -Can this convert a server database backup to a client database

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to use sync framework to synchronize large databases,but since the sizes of databases, it is really painful to deprovision and reprovision,when there are schema changes. Since the project is in Development stage, I want a fixed solution to provision client database without any time wasting way.
My question is, is it possible to restore a provisioned server DB to client DB &  run PerformPostRestoreFixup in client DB to save initial sync time?(also vice versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, that's your only other alternative for initialising new replicas with pre-loaded data. (the other one is generating snapshots via SQL CE).